# Opencart Journal REVOLUTION SLIDER

Tags: opencart

I make online store with opencart. I use  Journal 13 template, but on tablet and mobile version(after 1330px) REVOLUTION SLIDER became dual , one under the other.(Main Slider). If anybody have same problem or some idea how to fix it. 
Please tell me. Thanks in advance. Version of Opencart is 2.0.0.0

Answer (score 0):

In Journal template settings there is an option that you can select and show a slider only on mobile or tablet or in all devices. By the description of your problem I am pretty sure that you have 2 sliders enabled. One for mobile only and one for all devices. You need to change this and you will be ok.